# Javascript renders with a delay after HTML

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML page with a couple javascript buttons that 'replace' the HTML/CSS.

However, when the page loads, there is an annoying delay between when the HTML/CSS loads and when the js 'replaces' it . (An example of what I'm talking about can be seen on the site: www.psd2html.com). What accounts for this delay and what is the best practice in terms of having the js load before a user experiences a delay (for example on Facebook or Youtube or any other large site with lots of js). Thank you.

Comment: You can't avoid this delay and shouldn't try to avoid it. People are used to see elements loading one after the other on webpages and won't see that as a bug or even as something inelegant. I just checked web2html and it looked fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the delay define your `replaceElement()` function in `<head>` then use `<script>` tags inside `<body>` to call that function right after the element to be replaced is loaded:

```
...
<div id="to_be_replaced_1">contents or whatever</div>
<script type="text/javascript">replaceElement( 'to_be_replaced_1' );</script>
...
some other content
...
<div id="to_be_replaced_2">contents or whatever</div>
<script type="text/javascript">replaceElement( 'to_be_replaced_2' );</script>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually, people who answered that "it is probably better to accept it" got the point. Nevertheless, there are some approaches which can help you to reduce negative effects.

- Think twice about any UI element you want to change, to decorate, to repaint, to redraw dynamically. I mean, there must be a real reason why you are replacing something with javascript generated UI element with different layout.
- If it is not the option, if you just can't avoid replacing via javascript for some reasons, try to use some visual effect, some transition effect (is can be gained not only by css transitions, though) which give a user psychological evidence of that everything is OK, everything works as it should works. Sorta of disabled - disabled, but loading - enabled metaphor.